# Cakephp: how to Redirect to another controller in ajax

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

in my application am calling this line in case a particular case (if condition) from ajax call

$this->redirect('/login/login/');

But this was updating the particular div. I want to redirect the whole page. 
How to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you may need to do it the old way :)

```
window.opener.location.href = "new page";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can supply a parameter to redirect which will change the controller.

In an application I have written I use:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
```

when I want to prompt the user for a login.

You can find the full documentation for redirect here

http://book.cakephp.org/view/425/redirect